# Why did the Atom text editor make unexpected changes to these po files when I saved them?

Tags: character-encoding, po, atom-editor

I used [Atom](http://atom.io) to edit some PO translation files for the [Neovim project](http://www.github.com/neovim/neovim), but when I saved the files, Atom changed a bunch of other lines (which I did not edit) in each file.

You can see the results in [this commit](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/8e351ca359d1738a10f664f7ff252d96cdcdbc49). Basically each translation file has 5-10 other lines that git says are also changed.

I'm guessing there was some kind of encoding issue, can anyone provide a more detailed explanation?

Also, how do I edit these files without messing with the encoding?

Comment: So you had troubles using editor a to edit source files for editor n and you tag your question with editor v. You are right, why make it simple when we can make it complicated?

Comment: Sorry, an earlier version of the question asked if Vim would cause the same problem, I simplified the question and forgot to delete the vim tag

Comment: Atom strips trailing whitespace by default, this includes blank lines that are indented. Is this what is happening?

Comment: No--check the commit and you'll see that it was non-standard characters that were changing, not whitespace.